# Using login session from asp.net in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Is there a way I can use the session created by ASP.NET to authenticate my silverlight app? All I would need is the userID. Then I can call to my WCF RIA service to get roles, etc. If there is a better way to do this, please tell.

But I want to be able to login using html in asp.net. I'm using forms authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the user authentication context resides on the server and the SL resides on browser, you need to create a service layer in WCF to get these details. The WCF service needs to run in aspNetCompatibilityEnabled mode. Check details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx). Once you create such WCF service, you can expose methods on it such as GetLoggedInUser(), GetUserRoles() etc. 
I believe WCF RIA service make this work easier for you, so you can concentrate on main application logic.

Answer (score 0):

If the user id is all you need you can pass it as a custom initialization parameter to the Silverlight plugin. More info on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx